# SSRS ,Must Declare Scalar Variable error Query Data Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am using the following query even after the declaration of Parameter  getting error ,able to execute on SQL server but error on SSRS ,help me.

```
declare @Fromdate date = '1/1/2018' ,@Todate date ='12/31/2018' ,@Date nvarchar(10) 
Begin
   set @Date = left(convert(VARCHAR,@Fromdate,112),6)

   while @Fromdate <= @Todate
   Begin 
     SET @Fromdate = (select REPLACE 
                             (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MM,1,convert(date 
                      ,@Fromdate)),120),10),'-',''))
     if @Fromdate <= @Todate
     begin
        SET @Date  = left(convert(VARCHAR,@Fromdate,112),6)

        select @Date as Date
     END 
   END 
END
```

Comment: The error while refreshing the fields on data set is must declare the variable

Comment: The better question here is, why are you using a `WHILE` to get a list of dates (months) between 2 dates?

Comment: can u add screenshot of error message? Are you entering some values for your parameters while refreshing?

Comment: I can't see anything inherently "wrong" with that SQL; apart from that it's using a `WHILE` and that you have a couple  of `CONVERT(varchar,...` where you haven't declared then length of your `varchar`, neither of which are normally a good idea. This means that the query we have, in solitude, isn't the problem. I doubt that is your only Dataset in your report though, and that that SQL is the full statement; SSRS only interprets the first data set (so of the 11 rows returned above, it would only considering the first). I can confidently say we only have a couple of pieces of the puzzle here.

Comment: Consider having a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you further.

Comment: After the while there is piece of code executing where I am passing "@date" variable to that code where it execute the results everytime and insert into a temporary table ,please let me know if you have any better idea and "@date" is derived from "@fromdate" where I am declaring this one parameter.Like everytime the code executes with one month and returns few lines of code based on input month.

Comment: Exactly WHICH scalar variable does the error message say you need to declare?

Comment: Fromdate and Todate are declared in parameters ,I need to declare another variable which only 6 characters of @fromdate which needed to be iterated till todate for example Fromdate is 1/1/2018 and to date is 2/28/2018 then I should get to 201801 ,201802 dates dynamically where I can pass them into my code.

Comment: IS there any way I need to pass the dates dynamically to code based on fromdate and todate without using the while loop?

Comment: make sure your variable names are spelled exactly the same as the parameter names passing from the report, they are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes I passed them properly but something fishy its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing SSRS a single result set.  Maybe the following will work. The following uses a table variable to insert your dates and then selects them as a result set.

```
declare 
   @Fromdate date = '1/1/2018' ,
   @Todate date ='12/31/2018' ,
   @Date nvarchar(10) 

Declare @tbl Table (dt nVarChar(10))

Begin
   while @Fromdate <= @Todate
   Begin 
     SET @Fromdate = (select REPLACE 
                             (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MM,1,convert(date 
                      ,@Fromdate)),120),10),'-',''))
     if @Fromdate <= @Todate
     begin
        SET @Date  = left(convert(VARCHAR,@Fromdate,112),6)

        Insert Into @tbl Values (@Date)
     END 
   END 
END

Select * From @tbl
```

UPDATE:  Cleaned up a bit.  I confirmed this will work as a SSRS Dataset:

```
Declare @Fromdate date = '1/1/2018' 
Declare @Todate date ='12/31/2018' 

Declare @tbl Table (dt nVarChar(10))

    Begin
       while @Fromdate <= @Todate
       Begin 
         SET @Fromdate = (select REPLACE 
                                 (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MM,1,convert(date 
                          ,@Fromdate)),120),10),'-',''))
         if @Fromdate <= @Todate
         begin
            Insert Into @tbl Values (left(convert(VARCHAR,@Fromdate,112),6))
         END 
       END 
    END

    Select * From @tbl
```

SSRS:
[image]

If using a Stored Procedure and Pass Parameters to a Stored Proc:
[image]

Comment: I tried to execute this one but I am getting the following error " Parse error at line: 1, column: 14: Incorrect syntax near 'Table'."

Comment: Are you getting this error from SSMS or SSRS?  It should work from SSMS.  If you are running as a dataset from within SSRS, you might need to seperate the declarations.  See my update version...

Comment: Even the updated one is also not working ,same error.

Comment: I need to pass the From date and todate from parameters not from query.Try to refresh the fields by commenting the from and to dates

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly that you intend to use a Stored Procedure and pass variables from SSRS to the proc?  Then, you just need to setup SSRS parameters and map them to your proc variables.

Comment: No @Level3looper ,I am using query not the stored proc.

Comment: Same solution...  If you are placing this as a query in your report, then remove the fd and td declarations from the query and allow the report variables to be passed to the query.

Comment: I'm left to assume there is more going on in your report because the above query text without the declarations and mapped report parameters to query variables should work.  Perhaps, just to test, make a new report with only this stuff.

Comment: Yes tried with new report still its not working same error

Comment: One thing I have seen... (Someone with more savvy on 
SSRS might know why) - but - When setting up a query text as a dataset, you might need to keep the declarations in the query text and accept the query in the report so it creates the dataset field... Then remove the declarations to allow the report parameters to be used by the query text.  I'll set this up as a separate answer...

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have seen... (Someone with more savvy on 
SSRS might know why) - but - When setting up a query text as a dataset, you might need to keep the declarations in the query text at first and accept the query in the report so it creates the dataset field... Then remove the declarations to allow the report parameters to be used by the query text.

First, create a blank report and add two parameters:
[image]

Second, Create a dataset with Query text: (with declarations)
[image]

Third, add parameter maps to the dataset:
[image]

YOU SHOULD NOW SEE A [dt] field in the dataset:
[image]

Fourth, Remove the declarations from the Query text.  You will get prompted to define query parameters.  Hit OK.  It will say it can't update the list of fields.  Hit OK again.
[image]

Fifth, Go to the Table Wizard (under "Insert" - "Table") and add the [dt] field to the values section.
[image]

Finally, run the report and enter from and to dates:
[image]